# Asp.Net Identity - Custom Database Access UserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

Is is possible to extend the UserStore/UserManager to have access to a custom table within an override method (without creating another dbcontext)?

I'm working on a legacy database which we integrated with Identity. Recently we added a new table, Clients, to the database that has a one to one relationship with the Users table. What would like to do is override the FindAsync method in the UserManager class to do call the base method, grab the user, and then based on the user's client Id stored in the table, fetch the client name and insert that into the user model.

The following is what I have attempted; however, to me I think this is wrong approach and would like some suggestions on how to correctly apply what I'm trying to do.

```
public override async Task<ApplicationUser> FindAsync(string userName, string password)
{
    ApplicationUser user = await base.FindAsync(userName, password);

    if (user != null && user.ClientID != null)
    {
        using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext(HostPage.ConnectionString))
        {
            user.Client = ctx.Clients.Where(p => p.ClientID == user.ClientID).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify SQL in `base.FindAsync()` to perform a **join** to your table thus executing a single query.

Comment: The base class is a part of the Microsfot.AspNet.Identity namespace and I am unable to modify it.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: In that case you can bypass calling `base.FindAsync()` altogether and implement yourself. Otherwise your solution is just fine.

Comment: Gotcha, so there's no magic way around but to implement the database call myself using a custom store and what not?

Comment: Yes, I was sort of referring to custom store implementation originally. Also you might want to consider caching list of Clients in memory and obtain it from there, thus avoiding SQL call.